# Definition of Pólya-Laguerre class, and its property

Tags: complex-analysis

Here $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C})$ denotes the set of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$. In a note, it says

> An entire function $f$ belongs to the Pólya-Laguerre class (call it $\mathbf{PC}$) if it is limit in $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C})$ of real polynomials with only real roots.

What exactly does it mean? Does it mean, if we have a sequence of functions $(p_n)_{n\geq 0}$ that are real polynomials with only real roots, and if $p_n\to p$ for $n\to\infty$, where $p$ is some entire function, then $p\in \mathbf{PC}$? Is it correctly understood? Should $p_n\to p$ be pointwise or uniform?

Another question: How to prove:

> A function in $\mathbf{PC}$ is real with only real zeros

I think it is due to Rouché's Theorem, but I do not know how to prove it.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: limit is uniform on compact sets and the result quoted (real here means taylor coefficients at zero real or function conjugate invariant so $f(\bar z)=\bar f(z)$) holds by Hurwitz theorem

Comment: you need $p_n \to p$ locally uniformly; $p$ is an entire (complex analytic) function so real means real Taylor coefficients at zero or equivalently $p(\bar z)=\bar p(z)$; since $p_n$ obviously satisfy this because they are polynomials with real coefficients, $p$ will satisfy it too as $\bar p_n \to \bar p$; for the zero claim, Hurwitz shows that if $p$ (not identically zero of course) has a non-real root, $p_n$ must also have one for large enough $n$ and that contradicts the defintion of the class

Comment: @Conrad Sorry, I just want to make sure: by $\overline{p}(z)$ you mean that $\overline{p(z)}$?

Comment: sure - (by definition the function $\bar p$ is defined that way $\bar p(z)=\overline{p(z)}$) and it's a matter of preference how you use it (personally I prefer $\overline{p(z)}$ when emphasizing that the value is the conjugate value and $\bar p(z)$ when emphasizing that the function is the conjugate function)

Comment: @Conrad OK.Since $f$ is a real analytic it is real-valued so $f(\overline{z})=f(z)=\overline{f(z)}$,right?Assume contrary that a function $p\not\equiv 0$ in $\mathbf{PC}$ is a real analytic but with a non-real root $\alpha$ say of order $1$. Choose a sequence $(p_n)_{n\geq 0}$ of real polynomials with only real roots such that $p_n\to p$ locally unif.By Hurwitz there exists $\rho>0$ and $K\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $k\geq N$, $p_k$ has exactly $1$ zero in $\{z:|z-\alpha|<\rho\}$ counting multiplicity.But this is a contradiction, because $p_n$ must only have real roots.Is this how it is?

Comment: yes and to be explicit you can choose $\rho$ small enough so $|z-\alpha| < \rho$ implies $z$ non-real- though one has to be careful about the first statement ($f(\overline{z})=f(z)=\overline{f(z)}$ is true only for $z \in \mathbb R$ - entire nonconstant functions take all values but at most one; real polynomials also take complex values at complex numbers and they are surjective as maps from $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$

Comment: @Conrad OK, thank you. If you can collect them into an answer, I would accept it. By the way, I made another post about this subject as well. If you have time, look at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3810000/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments: since $p_n$ have real coefficients, $p_n(\bar z)=\overline {p_n(z)}, z \in \mathbb C$; taking limits on  $\overline {D(0,R)}$ for large $R$, one gets $p(\bar z)=\overline {p(z)}, z \in \mathbb C$, hence the entire function $p$ is conjugate-invariant or "real" - though one has to be careful and undertsnad that in the proper sense $p(x) \in \mathbb R, x \in \mathbb R$, not that $p$ takes only real values

(as conjugate invariant implies $p(x) \in \mathbb R, x \in \mathbb R$, then taking limits on the real axis, it follows that the Taylor coefficients at zero or at any real, are real which implies $p$ conjugate invariant, so these three properties are equivalent and either one can and is used in the definition of conjugate invariant/real)

Similarly if $p$ were to have a non-real root $\alpha$, one can pick a small $0<r <|\Im \alpha|$ so the disc of center $\alpha$ and radius $r$ doesn't intersect the real axis; by Hurwitz theorem $p_n$ must have a root in this disc for large $n$ and that is a contradiction to the hypothesis, so $p$ has indeed all real roots and we are done!