# $y\mapsto |E(x+iy)|$ is non-decreasing on $[0,\infty)$, where $E$ is in the Laguerre–Pólya class.

Tags: complex-analysis

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre%E2%80%93P%C3%B3lya_class), it mentions that

> $|E(x+iy)|$ is a non-decreasing function of $y$ for positive $y$.

where $E$ is in the Laguerre–Pólya class. How to check it? What I think is: Since $E$ is in the class, there exists a sequence $(p_n)_{n\geq 1}$ such that $p_n\to E$ locally uniformly in this context. Thus, we may write $p_n(x):=a\prod_{k=1}^n(x-x_k)$, where $x_1,\dots, x_n$ are real roots. Then
$$
|p_n(x+iy)|=|a|\prod_{k=1}^{n}((x-x_k)^2+y^2)^2
$$
The right-hand side is increasing in $y$ on $[0,\infty)$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$. So, since $p_n\to E$ locally uniformly, so does $|p_n|\to |E|$ locally uniformly. I am not sure, if the limit still holds for monotonicity.

Comment: fix $x, 0 \le y_1<y_2$ then $|p_n(x+iy_1)| \le |p_n(x+iy_2)|$ so one can let $n \to \infty$ and get $|E(x+iy_1)| \le |E(x+iy_2)|$

Comment: @Conrad Oh, that's easier than I thought. Thank you! I come to think of another thing, because of the constant value $a$ or/and having $p_n$ exactly $n$ roots I made in my post: I want to make it in more general: If $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is ANY sequence of real polynomials with only real roots, how should the product look like? Something with $f_n(x)=a_n\prod_{k=1}^{N_n}(x-x_k)$, where $a_n\in \mathbb{R}$ non-zero, $N_n$ is a natural number depending on $n$, and $\{x_1,\dots, x_{N_n}\}$ is the set of real roots? Or is there a precise way to express?

Comment: @Conrad Or maybe $f_n(x)=a_n\prod_{k=1}^{N_m}(x-x_{n,k})$, where $x_{n,1},\dots, x_{n,N_n}$ are the real roots of $f_n$?

Comment: depends on how formal you want to make it, which dependences to emphasize; the way is done in the OP is just fine for the result one needs since the required inequality holds at level $n$, not between levels, so one doesn't need to emphasize the dependence on $n$; note also that it is not necessary to assume that $f_n$ has degree $n$ though one can find in this case a sequence of degree $n$ polynomials that works if $p$ is not a polynomial itself (Laguerre-Polya class has a very precise description and functions like $e^z, e^{-z^2}, 1+z, z^k$ are part of it, while $e^{z^2}$ is not)